# Why is Joanna sometimes seen in bondage in "Mr. Robot"?

Tags: plot-explanation, mr-robot

I noticed that in an episode of season 1 and in season 2, we see Tyrell's wife in bondage. Why is that? Is there some significance or symbolism besides sex appeal?

Comment: Might as well ask why Krista's (Elliot's psychiatrist) favorite porno category is "anal". Objectification? Racism? Brainwashing? No, it's simple. It's an on going show, they are building characters, exploring possibilities. Give it a time.

Comment: @Lettmannen, I think there's a better answer. One of the main themes of the season 2 premier was that control is an illusion. We think of people in bondage as being the submissive one, but it is later revealed that it's actually Joanna who has control over the guy.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

One of the main themes of the season 2 premier was that "control is an illusion." We think of people in bondage as being the submissive ones, but it is later revealed that it's actually Joanna who has control over the guy she is having sex with. I think this scene adds on to the theme of control.

Answer (score 1):

She has a high tolerance for pain, likes being submissive and not in control. I think where her bondage comes into play in terms of character development is when she provoked Scott to the point of beating her. The point was to get him to beat her and commit a crime so she can either have him arrested or have leverage on him. Most people wouldn't put themselves in such a situation, but she has a higher tolerance for pain and less fear of it. She frequently puts herself in situations where she seemingly has no control, but she knows she has, or will, regain it. So she is at ease here too.